# C# . How to take effect for regitstry edited Caret Width immediately?

Tags: c#, winapi, registry

I found a path for Caret Width in my registry: **HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1217365396-2387141574-3682890637-1001\Control Panel\Desktop**. Value "**CaretWidth**" = 1. 
 I want to change it for 5, for example.
But how take effect for this change immediately? 
I think need to use some method from pinvoke.net, but I don't know how do it.
 Can you help me?

Comment: This setting is read when the user signs in.  To make it take effect, sign out and sign back in.  If you don't like that, I guess you could complain to Microsoft.  It's a Windows 10 feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // Add

    namespace Caret_Changer
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            const int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
            const int SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02;
            public const uint SPI_SETCARETWIDTH = 0x2007;

            [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
            public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, uint pvParam, uint fWinIni);

            private void ChangeCaret(uint caret)
            {
                SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCARETWIDTH, 0, caret, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
            }

            // Start button
            private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ChangeCaret(0x0000005); // New caret width
            }

            // Stop Button
            private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ChangeCaret(0x0000001); // Return default width
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution! And you could also [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SystemParametersInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) and pass `SPI_SETCARETWIDTH`